# Access to people denied - Linkedin API Javascript

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I'm using the LinkedIn JavaScript API

I have this error 'Access to people denied' my code is:

```
IN.API.PeopleSearch().params({ "first-name": "Barack" }).result(saveProfiles).error(displayProfilesErrors);
```

I added this line to the script configuration:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: my_key
    authorize: true
    scope: r_fullprofile r_network r_emailaddress r_contactinfo
</script>
```

The Application has been implemented to accept all these features.

Comment: I'm shocked to see that [the LinkedIn JavaScript API docs](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/javascript-api-tutorial) tell you to create a `script` tag like that. It's shocking because it's a violation of the spec: Inline content in a [`script` tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) with a `src` [must be comments](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#inline-documentation-for-external-scripts). But that's what they tell you to do.

Comment: Are you authenticating the member? (See *Authenticating the Member* [on this page](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/javascript-api-tutorial).)

Comment: Yes, first of all, I authenticate the user using: 
        <script type="IN/Login" data-onauth="loadData"></script> and before I call to PeopleSearch function I validate the user using:  if (IN.User.isAuthorized()) {IN.API.PeopleSearch....}
    </div>

Answer (score 1):

You may beed "Vetted API Access".

Go to https://help.linkedin.com/app/api-dvr and apply for "Vetted API Access Request".